# How to default/force the user's display_name to their nickname?

Tags: users

I'm creating a simple directory from the user accounts and want to simplify it as much as possible for the users. I changed the label on nickname to Lastname, Firstname so that the users can be alphabetized by the nickname field, but I want the display_name to default, or even force, to the nickname field. I haven't seen a plugin, so I'm looking for something I can add to the functions to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force this with a hook that activates when the profile is updated. The next step would be to hide the `display_name` select box, you can do that with some Javascript.

```
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'wpse7352_set_user_display_name_to_nickname', 10, 3 );
function wpse7352_set_user_display_name_to_nickname( &$errors, $update, &$user )
{
    if ( ! empty( $user->nickname ) ) {
        $user->display_name = $user->nickname;
    }
}
```